# How do I setup a simple SVN server?

Tags: svn, version-control, svnadmin, svnserve, svn-checkout

I have a working repository that I created a long time ago, and now I'm trying to set up another, but I'm having great difficulty. Here's what I did to create the second one; and I would expect this to work:

```
U:\repos>svnadmin create repo1
U:\repos>echo password-db = passwd >> repo1/conf/svnserve.conf
U:\repos>echo auth-access = write >> repo1/conf/svnserve.conf
U:\repos>echo user1 = user >> repo1/conf/passwd
U:\repos>cd repo1
U:\repos\repo1>svnserve -d
```

And in another terminal:

```
U:\>mkdir wc
U:\>cd wc
U:\wc>svn co svn://localhost/repo1
svn: E210005: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://localhost/repo1'
svn: E210005: No repository found in 'svn://localhost/repo1'
U:\wc>
```

The other repository is configured in the same way at `u:\repo`. What's going on?

Comment: It might be worth to look into alternatives like http://www.visualsvn.com/ which are very easy in use, setup is done in a few clicks and creating and managing repositories also. I know this is a little bit off your question, but still as a comment it can't hurt much to add it. :)

Comment: @MrMichael Excellent comment, and welcome. I was going for a command-line only (and svn-tools-only, that is, no third-party) solution because I want something very portable, small, no install, _etc_.

Comment: @MrMichael *Portable? Small? No install?* Do you know that you can access Subversion repository without any server? I.e. you can access a repository directly on disk via `file:///URL`. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.multimethod.html

Comment: @bahrep Old news, still most people prefer eyecandy and simple management in stead of commandline tools. For me personally SVN won't do the trick, it does not offer the features i demand from source control, which Mercurial/Git do offer.

Comment: @MrMichael Ehm. Looks like I understand your point. However I don't understand how it relates to my comment :))

Comment: @bahrep I was trying to say that not everyone is comfortable with commandline tools, so i just threw it in as a suggestion if someone is struggling. Also, i did not say "Portable? Small? No install?" that was the poster although i would not think of SVN with that criterea, unless working alone. :P

Comment: @bahrep Was your first comment aimed at me? Thanks for that info; I was only vaguely aware of this feature. I do plan on disconnecting from the repository on a regular basis, so a working copy is fairly essential. As you see from the answer, I got it set up; thanks again!

Comment: @LimitedAtonement Eek! Yep, it was aimed at you but I missed xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `cd repo1` is superfluous: `svnserve` doesn't care about the working directory in this instance.

To make your example work, change `-d` to `-d -r \repos`.

Alternatively, you could change your `co` command to `svn co svn://localhost/repos/repo1`.

When `svn co` is run, it's using the URL to tell `svnserve` where to look for the repo. This path by default is relative to `/`, not the working directory where `svnserve` was launched! The existing repository works because the repo happens to be in `/`, not because `svnserve` was launched from `/repo`. When you want the path of your repo to be referenced from somewhere other than `/`, use the `-r [--root]` option of `svnserve`.

This means that a repository stored at `u:\repos\repo1`, when launched with `svnserve -r u:\repos` must be referenced by the url `/repo1` (`svn://localhost/repo'`) rather than `/repos/repo1`. Capish?

Comment: @Mawg Thanks for the suggestion. Accepted.